# Get_template_part inside a folder

Tags: functions, page-template, get-template-part

So I've the following code in order to search for templates inside a custom theme I'm working on:

```
<?php $my_theme = wp_get_theme();
get_template_part( 'masthead',  $my_theme->Template); ?>
```

Basically what it does, is that it does a search for a file called "masthead-themename.php". If that file does not exists, then it looks for a file called "masthead.php". This works as expected.

However, I would to have something that searches for the file inside of a folder called "templates" as a first option and if not, then search for the template name in the theme's root folder.

I tried this

```
<?php $my_theme = wp_get_theme();
get_template_part( 'templates/masthead',  $my_theme->Template); ?>
```

But this only works if the file exists in the template's folder. If the file exists in the root's theme folder, it does not recognize it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a file in `templates/masterhead-templatename.php`, and it works, it is ok.

Correct me if I am wrong, you want to locate this file like this `masterhead-templatename.php`, basically one folder up, but this wordpress function does not work like this.

> If the file exists in the root's theme folder, it does not recognize it.

It is not supposed to do so. 
It searches for a file `templates/masterhead.php`, since`templates/masterhead-templatename.php` was not found.

---

The function specification `get_template_part( 'templates/masthead',  $my_theme->Template);` searches like this:

```
STYLESHEETPATH/templates/masthead-themename.php
STYLESHEETPATH/templates/masthead.php
TEMPLATEPATH/templates/masthead-themename.php
TEMPLATEPATH/templates/masthead.php
```

Which file is found, that is included and the searching obviously stops.